# Chromium MIDI setup on Linux

Tags: linux, audio, chromium, gentoo, midi

I'm currently trying to work out how MIDI is supposed to work in Chromium on Linux. I'm on Gentoo. I've got Chromium 52.0.2743.60 installed. The midi access object obtained from navigator.requestMIDIAccess has an output map of length zero, so apparently chromium doesn't know of any MIDI outputs on my system.

I don't have any MIDI hardware connected. I fired up Qsynth and qjackctl and VMPK and managed to get sound from VMPK to my speakers, so I seem to have a working MIDI pipeline. I see the connection from VMPK to FLUID Synth in the qjackctl connections window, in the ALSA tab. But I don't see Chromium as a possible MIDI source there.

What do I have to do to connect chromium to my software synthesizer? Are there any manuals about this? I couldn't find any. Are there any steps along the path I could check to narrow the problem down?

Comment: I'm afraid nix is not my forte, but internal 'soft synth to sequencer' connections are unlikely to be using MIDI per se. MIDI is really for connection to legacy external hardware devices, via some kind of USB/MIDI adaptor. Mac uses IAC Bus natively, or Rewire as a 3rd party structure, maybe see if there are nix equivalents...

Comment: Maybe this is not too helpful, but at least I've been able to get MIDI input to be detected and used by Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04. I've only tested it on Pianu.com (you may check https://pianu.com/test-my-connection , although the website is working slow today for some reason). I didn't have to do anything special just open VMPK or Virtual MIDI Keyboard and it just worked™ - not sure exactly how, though, Chromium never appears as an ALSA MIDI input or anything like that, it seems it just "sniffs" every MIDI event.